# Как правильно организовать связи в таблицах для динамического перевода на свйте

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

Нужно сделать систему переводов, но не могу правильно составить связи в таблицах…
Есть набор таблиц
`news, posts, page_metadata, translations и translation_keys`
В таблице `translations` поля `id, language_id, translator_key_id, content, singular`  в таблице `translation_keys` поля `id, key`
Допустим нужно создать переводы (meta) для поста, в таблице `translation_keys` создаю записи с ключами `post.meta_content_title, post.meta_content_description` после чего в таблице `translations` создаю все названия и описания на нужном языке (поле `singular` используется для уникальности, чтоб нельзя было создать один и тот же ключ с таким же языкам) далее в таблице `page_metadata` с набор полей `id, translation_id, page_type, relation_id` создаю запись в которой указано `translation_id` на нужный перевод, `page_type` используется для обозначения какой тип используется (в данном случае посты, это для того чтоб знать на какую запись ссылается поле relation_id), `relation_id` указываю для какого поста эта запись, если запись должна быть для общих страниц таких как о нас, контакты… поле `relation_id` идет null.

Теперь если мне нужно выбрать перевод meta к примеру для главной страницы сайта я делаю запрос
`select * from page_metadata pm inner join translations t on t.id = pm.translation_id inner join languages l l.id = t.language_id inner join translation_keys tk tk.id = t.translation_key_id where page_type is null and l.code = ‘ru-RU’ and tk.key in (‘main.meta_content_title’, ‘main.meta_content_description’)`

Все работает, но мне кажется что я что-то делаю не так, как-то слишком много таблиц и все очень запутанно, а также нет способа выбрать другой язык есть записи на запрашиваемом нет

Может у кого есть опыт в реализации таких механизмов?

P.S. Использую ларавель и базу постгрес

Answer (score -1):

Использовать готовую библиотеку.
например https://github.com/spatie/laravel-translatable

ps полям с переводами в БД сменить тип на json

Comment: Не особо удачная реализация потому что хранить данные в json это такой себе вариант, если это использовать для маленького сайта и хранить там слова или строки небольшого размера, это хороший выбор, то что нужно мне это как просто слова, так и целые предложения, а также огромные текста.

Второй момент к минусу библиотеки это то что нет управления языками.